# Reading PDF file using OpenCV

Tags: c++, pdf, opencv

Is it possible to convert a PDF file to `cv::Mat`?
I know that PDF file is generally vector of objects, but given a required resolution. Is there any tool that can do such a conversion?

Comment: what are you talking about?  PDF files are documents~!

Comment: PDF files are anything you would like them to be. They may contain text, images, graphs, links ,etc. I would like to convert the image you see with the viwer into an image. pdf2bmp are common, and I would like an API to convert pdf to cv::Mat.

Comment: why don't you convert to bitmap and load the bitmap to opencv

Comment: Did not find any good c++ API that can convert PDF to image with a given DPI.

Comment: What can you say about my answer below?

Comment: Had to check it before I answer. Yes The link you supplied did help, just need to combine imagemagick with opencv. thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't support pdf format at all, so you should convert pdf page to image using another library. Read this discussion: [Open source PDF library for C/C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730/open-source-pdf-library-for-c-c-application)

Also this question is similar to yours: [What C++ library can I use to convert a PDF to an image on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603615/what-c-library-can-i-use-to-convert-a-pdf-to-an-image-on-windows)